# Is there an elegant way to implement this function: `(Monad m) => (s -> a -> m (s, b)) -> s -> [a] -> m [b]`

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

A function like `(Monad m) => (s -> a -> m (s, b))` producing a new state and a new value based on the previous state and the current value is quite frequent.

We can use different approaches for implementing a traversal of a list of `a` to produce a `m [b]` given a function `f :: s -> a -> m (s, b)`

- using `Control.Monad.foldM` but the code is not particularly nice
- using `traverse` and a `StateT (WriterT m)` monad, which is a bit better

Is there a good use of existing libraries to decompose the "state-defined behaviour" with the "output behaviour" of `f` and get the desired traversal in a few combinators?

Comment: Would `m (s, [b])` work as the result type instead?  That's much easier to get.

Comment: I could indeed `fst <$>` that which I would like to avoid if possible but please share your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain `StateT` suffices,

```
foo :: Monad m => (s -> a -> m (s, b)) -> s -> [a] -> m [b]
foo g = flip (evalStateT . mapM (StateT . f))
   where
   f a s = liftM swap $ g s a

swap (a,b) = (b,a)   -- or import Data.Tuple
```

`flip` and `f` make the pieces fit, if you must use your exact types instead of the more natural type `a -> s -> m (b, s)`.

Comment: `\(a,b) -> (b,a)` has a name, `Data.Tuple.swap`

Answer (score 3):

Up to newtype nonsense, we have:

```
traverse @[] @(StateT s m) :: (a -> s -> m (a, s)) -> [a] -> s -> m ([b], s)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, `StateT` is indeed enough

Answer (score 2):

Based on Will Ness's answer and because I have the opportunity to rearrange arguments in my code I can get the following

```
foldAccumulate :: (Monad m) => (a -> s -> m (b, s)) -> [a] -> s -> m [b]
foldAccumulate f = evalStateT . traverse (StateT . f)
```

Which is indeed a `traverse` with the appropriate `StateT m` monad, and there's no need for writing anything, I don't know why I did not see that :-). Thanks!

Comment: If you absolutely must avoid using `StateT` in the wrapper, you might like to turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` and sundry other extensions, then use `foldAccumulate :: forall m s a b. ...; foldAccumulate = coerce (traverse @[] @(StateT s m) @a @b)` to replace the (cheap, but not completely free) newtype wrapping and unwrapping with (the completely free) mere coercion. You can also relax your `Monad` constraint to `Applicative`.